# Beamer -- adding space between itemize environments

Tags: beamer, itemize

The code below does not add a space between the two environments, despite the "//" new line macro (output shown below). Is there a right to do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A title}

Topic 1
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4 \\
\end{itemize} 

Topic 2
\begin{itemize} 
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `\bigskip`? (between `\end{itemize}` and `Topic 2`).

Comment: I was hoping for a more systematic solution and less *ad hoc* solution, ideally one that would be sensitive to how much space is left (kind of like \vfill)

Comment: Well, `\vfill` then...

Comment: Vfill will push the two environments to the top and bottom, respectively, which is of course not aesthetic in a presentation

Comment: I guess I know what you mean. Add one `\vfill` before the first itemize, one `\vfill` between the two itemizes and one after the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can sprinkle `\vfill` to taste:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A title}
\vfill
Topic 1
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4 \\
\end{itemize} 
\vfill
Topic 2
\begin{itemize} 
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]